# Nodejs mssql unhandled promise when Connection Times out

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

The case is simple: I'm using npm mssql package to stablish database connections using pooling method. To init the pool I just do:

```
const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    console.log('<---- POOL CONNECTED TO MSSQL ---->')
    return pool;
  }, error => {
    console.log('<---- DATABASE IS DOWN ---->')
  }).catch(err => {
    // HERE I LOG THE ERROR SOMEWHERE ELSE
    console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err)
  });

module.exports = {
  sql, poolPromise
}
```

Now, the problem is that the database server is kind of unstable right now. Sometimes it goes down for a while. Is a proble that the DB guys must fix, but I want to be able to notify the UI that the DB is down a some point. However, the exception that's rised is not captured by the catch block there. It just writes in the nodejs console the following:

---

```
(node:2962) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to <serverIP>:1433 - connect ETIMEDOUT <severIP>:1433
    at Connection.tedious.once.err (/project/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:239:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Connection.socketError (/project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1024:14)
    at /project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:868:25
    at Socket.onError (/project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js:49:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
(node:2962) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2962) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.


----
```

Do you guys have any idea on how to capture this particular event to be logged properly. ?

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your pool, you can listen to an "error" event and handle it accordingly within the callback.

```js
const pool = new Sql.Pool();

pool.on("error", () => {
  // handle error accordingly
});
```